# I want to show all api data into the table view. It only shows the first dictionary element of api

Tags: ios, swift, api, tableview

I am fetching data through api and save it into init. when i show this data into table view then it only shows the first value of dictionary. I want to show all the values of dictionary into my table view.

class :

```
class FetchedDeparment
{
    var depttName: String
    var createdDate: String

    init(depttName: String, createdDate: String) {

        self.depttName = depttName
        self.createdDate = createdDate
    }
}
```

fetching data from api and save it init.

```
var fetchedDepttData = [FetchedDeparment]()
fetchedDepttData = []

self.arrDeptt = json["departments"] as! [[String : Any]]
print(self.arrDeptt)

for eachDepartment in json["departments"]!
{
    let eachData = eachDepartment as! [String: Any]
    let depttName = eachData["name"] as! String
    let createdDate = eachData["created_at"] as! String

    self.fetchedDepttData.append(FetchedDeparment.init(depttName: depttName, createdDate: createdDate))
}
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

TableView :
This is where i want to show all the data.

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return fetchedDepttData.count
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DepartmentCell", for: indexPath) as! ShowDepttTVCell

        cell.lblDepttName.text = fetchedDepttData[indexPath.row].depttName
        cell.lblCreatedDate.text = fetchedDepttData[indexPath.row].createdDate

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: You did a mistake to declare a number of sections and number of rows in tableview. take a look in both methods and correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is okay. You have to replace the row with section because you are counted the array in numberOfSection table view data source method.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DepartmentCell", for: indexPath) as! ShowDepttTVCell

        cell.lblDepttName.text = fetchedDepttData[indexPath.section].depttName
        cell.lblCreatedDate.text = fetchedDepttData[indexPath.section].createdDate

        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do it
first 
1.  var DataYouWant: [[String:Any]] = [String:Any]
this how you will pull the data using alamofire
2.

```
func demoApi() {
        Alamofire.request("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

            switch(response.result) {

            case .success(_):
                guard let json = response.result.value as! [[String:Any]]? else{ return}
                print("Response \(json)")
                for item in json {

                    self.DataYouWant.append(item)

                    // if let title = item["title"] as? String {
                    //   self.titleArray.append(title)
                    // }

                }
                if !self.getAllDetail.isEmpty{
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                         self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
                break

            case .failure(_):
                print("Error")
                break

            }
        }

}
```

3. this how you numberOfSections would look like 
   func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
           return 1
       }
4. and then

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
           return DataYouWant.count
       }

tell me if you have another questions